# Select all answer fields should also be present

Tags: support

Like *"unselect all **'response'** fields"* would get displayed when we click on any of the fields marked in the snapshot below, same way there should be - *"select all **'response'** fields"*[image]
Similarly, one link should be present, clicking on which we can select all fields of all responses and another link to unselect all fields of all responses.